# Learning Bash Conditionals - Syntax errors

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement

Okay. I've been banging my head up against the Linux wall again. What am I doing incorrectly here:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo
echo "1. Windows (Microsoft)
echo  2. Linux (Red Hat)
echo  3. MacOS (Apple)
echo
echo -n Select your OS choice [1, 2 or 3]: "
READ OS
echo

if [ "$OS" -eq 1 ]; then
echo "You picked Windows (Microsoft)."
fi
if [ "$OS" -eq 2 ]; 
echo "You picked Linux (Red Hat)."
fi
if [ "$OS" -eq 3 ]; then
echo "You picked MacOS (Apple)."
fi
if [ "$OS" > 3 || "$OS" < 1 ]];
echo "Invalid selection!"
fi
exit 1
```

**error message**:

```
[ : : integer expression expected
```

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: What does [ShellCheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) say? (it will tell you exactly what is wrong -- and save your head from the wall) And use a string comparison `[ "$OS" = "1" ]` instead of an arithmetic `-eq` comparison.

Comment: It will save lots of headaches `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the wrong if/elif/else syntax:

```
if [ "$OS" -eq 1 ] 
then
    echo "You picked Windows (Microsoft)."
elif [ "$OS" -eq 2 ] 
then 
     echo "You picked Linux (Red Hat)."
elif [ "$OS" -eq 3 ] 
then
     echo "You picked MacOS (Apple)."
else 
     echo "Invalid selection!"
fi
exit 1
```

Also if you want to use greater or inferior, you should use `-gt` or `-lt`etc. 
Please refer to this page: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

also have a look at the syntax of `or` and `and` at this link: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html#ANDOR

Also I have just spotted it by your should have the same number of opening square brackets than closing ones.

After fixing all the issues in the script:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo
echo "1. Windows (Microsoft)"
echo "2. Linux (Red Hat)"
echo "3. MacOS (Apple)"
echo
echo -n "Select your OS choice [1, 2 or 3]: "
read OS
echo

if [ "$OS" -eq 1 ] 
then
    echo "You picked Windows (Microsoft)."
elif [ "$OS" -eq 2 ] 
then 
     echo "You picked Linux (Red Hat)."
elif [ "$OS" -eq 3 ] 
then
     echo "You picked MacOS (Apple)."
else 
     echo "Invalid selection!"
fi
exit 0
```

**Producing the following output at execution:**

```
arobert@arobert-VirtualBox [11:48:52]
[/home/arobert/test_awk] >
./ostype.sh 

1. Windows (Microsoft)
2. Linux (Red Hat)
3. MacOS (Apple)

Select your OS choice [1, 2 or 3]: 2

You picked Linux (Red Hat).
arobert@arobert-VirtualBox [11:48:56]
[/home/arobert/test_awk] >
./ostype.sh 

1. Windows (Microsoft)
2. Linux (Red Hat)
3. MacOS (Apple)

Select your OS choice [1, 2 or 3]: 1

You picked Windows (Microsoft).
arobert@arobert-VirtualBox [11:49:00]
[/home/arobert/test_awk] >
./ostype.sh 

1. Windows (Microsoft)
2. Linux (Red Hat)
3. MacOS (Apple)

Select your OS choice [1, 2 or 3]: 3 

You picked MacOS (Apple).
arobert@arobert-VirtualBox [11:49:05]
[/home/arobert/test_awk] >
./ostype.sh 

1. Windows (Microsoft)
2. Linux (Red Hat)
3. MacOS (Apple)

Select your OS choice [1, 2 or 3]: 5

Invalid selection!
```

Comment: Hmmm...still getting syntax errors of " [ : : integer expression expected

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: will change it directly! sorry for that

Comment: @Allan, It appears I was just putting the 'then' on the same line as the argument. Fixed.

Comment: @Hebruiser Putting `then` on the same line as the condition is fine, provided you separate them with a semicolon. In shell syntax, a semicolon and a line break are mostly equivalent. Also, I think you're mixing syntaxes for `[ ]` and `[[ ]]`, and using integer comparison (`-eq`) when string comparison (`=`) would be better, iin case the user types in something other than a number. See [BashFAQ #31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) for some useful info.